# Getting java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: connect timed out while making a call to datastore

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

My application works fine locally and I'm able to connect to GCP Datastore from local. But when deployed to a server, I'm getting the below exception.

```
Caused by: com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: I/O error\n\t
at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:136)\n\t
at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:105)\n\t
at com.google.datastore.v1.client.Datastore.beginTransaction(Datastore.java:79)\n\t
at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.beginTransaction(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:153)\n\t... 92 common frames omitted\nCaused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: connect timed out\n\t
at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:444)\n\t
at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:157)\n\t
at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:145)\n\t
at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.getRequestMetadata(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:603)\n\t
at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize(HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:91)\n\t
at com.google.cloud.http.HttpTransportOptions$1.initialize(HttpTransportOptions.java:159)\n\t
at com.google.cloud.http.CensusHttpModule$CensusHttpRequestInitializer.initialize(CensusHttpModule.java:109)\n\t
at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc$1.initialize(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:91)\n\t
at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:91)\n\t... 94 common frames omitted\nCaused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out\n\t
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)\n\t
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)\n\t
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)\n\t
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)\n\t
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)\n\t
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)\n\t
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:285)\n\t
at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)\n\t
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)\n\t
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)\n\t
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:265)\n\t
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:372)\n\t
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)\n\t
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1181)\n\t
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1075)\n\t
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)\n\t
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1356)\n\t
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1331)\n\t
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:241)\n\t
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:113)\n\t
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)\n\t
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)\n\t
at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:441)
```

Edit -
Scopes under this credential

```
[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub,
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.admin,
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.data, 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore, 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin, 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only, 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write, 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudruntimeconfig, 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append, 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform, 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision, 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery, 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write]
```

Any lead will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: See if this helps you https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-datastore/issues/86

Comment: @SusanMustafa Thank you for the quick reply Susan. I did see that article before posting the question. That didn't help.

Comment: Curious if you actually authenticated it? gcloud auth application-default login

Comment: The credential is stored as an encoded key in the properties file. So, that should not be the problem. I've verified it.

Comment: Deployed to **what** server? How is that server configured for networking? If Compute Engine, which scopes are assigned to the default service account?

Comment: Put the content of your comment in your question and not as a comment (too hard to read).

Comment: Can you please check if [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802435/got-error-whenever-trying-to-get-access-token-from-service-account) answers your question ?

Comment: @RajeevTirumalasetty - That didn't help. But thank you for the comment.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turned out that it was a connectivity issue. Our server (in AWS) didn't have the right to access datastore.

Comment: Your post is not an answer, but a clarification of your problem. What changes did you make to solve **the right to access datastore**?